# Rendering an object with different shaders from different cameras in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, shader

In the space exploration game I'm working on, I've got a standard camera pointing 'forward' from the player's position. I've also got a HUD camera that points at the current planet or space station the player has selected.

I'd like to render this object using different shaders for the 2 different cameras.

A google search turned up this question (and answer) on the Unity Answers site:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/865507/rendering-same-object-on-two-cameras-with-differen.html

...but the Unity Scripting API page it links to is not very detailed in HOW to make it work. I also don't think I just need to set override tags.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetOverrideTag.html

Does anyone know how to render a single object differently, depending on which camera view is currently being rendered?